# Is there a built-in Python function to generate 100 numbers from 0 to 1?

Tags: python, math, loops, range, sequence

I am looking for something like `range`, but one that will allow me to specify the start and the end value, along with how many numbers I need in the collection which I want to use in a similar fashion `range` is used in `for loops`.

Comment: no. Use `numpy.linspace`

Comment: I would like to use other libraries but since this is the python integration of a 3rd party software, adding new libraries is very painful.

Comment: Like the R function [seq(from,to,length)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Generating-regular-sequences) and its [docpage](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/library/base/html/seq.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in function to do what you want. But, you can always define your own `range`:

```
def my_range(start, end, how_many):
    incr = float(end - start)/how_many
    return [start + i*incr for i in range(how_many)]
```

And you can using in a for-loop in the same way you would use `range`:

```
>>> for i in my_range(0, 1, 10):
...     print i
... 
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
```

**EDIT:** If you want both `start` and `end` to be part of the result, your `my_range` function would be:

```
def my_range(start, end, how_many):
    incr = float(end - start)/(how_many - 1)
    return [start + i*incr for i in range(how_many-1)] + [end]
```

And in your for-loop:

```
>>> for i in my_range(0, 1, 10):
...   print i
... 
0.0
0.111111111111
0.222222222222
0.333333333333
0.444444444444
0.555555555556
0.666666666667
0.777777777778
0.888888888889
1
```

Comment: Thanks but in my case, I need both the stand and the end to be in the sequence.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't have a floating point range function but you can simulate one easily with a list comprehension:

```
>>> lo = 2.0
>>> hi = 12.0
>>> n = 20
>>> [(hi - lo) / n * i + lo for i in range(n)]
[2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5]
```

Note, in numeric applications, people typically want to include both endpoints rather than have a half-open interval like Python's built-in *[range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range)* function.  If you need both end-points you can easily add that by changing `range(n)` to `range(n+1)`.

Also, consider using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which has tools like *[arange()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)* and *[linspace()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)* already built in.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me how I can do that that I can use in a for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the example, can it also include hi as the last element?

Comment: @Joan that conflicts with `range`'s behavior, so I would generally avoid that.

Comment: Oh ok, then I wouldn't use this, because I want to have the both ends included in the sequence, from 0 to 1 in my case, but I see your point.

Comment: @JoanVenge Edited the answer to show how to include both end-points by changing ``range(n)`` to ``range(n+1)``.

Comment: Thanks yeah it does what I need, but not sure which one to mark yet, as I am still using a simple range function in my code but liked the numpy solution even though it's not built-in.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `range`, you know. You just need to start out big, then divide:

```
for x in range(100):
    print x/100.0
```

If you want to include the endpoint:

```
for x in range(101):
    print x/100.0
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now, but figured there might be a nitfy method that does this.

Comment: may be you can make it more generic, with low, high and count.

Comment: Actually I can't use this either, as this also doesn't include 100 in the sequence ):

Answer (score 2):

There is a special function in numpy to do this: `linspace`. Ofcourse you will have to install numpy first. You can find more about it [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html).