# What's the most elegant way to write this for loop in Python?

Tags: python, math, loops, for-loop

Basically I want to go from -1 to 1 in `n` steps, including -1 and 1:

```
x = -1.0
n = 21

for i in range(n):
    print x
    x += 0.01

-1.0 -0.9 -0.8 ... 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

How can I write this in the most elegant, simplest way for any `n` value?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652006

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
startValue = -1.0
intervalLength = 2.0
numberOfSteps = 14
increasePerStep = intervalLength / numberOfSteps

print startValue

x = startValue
for i in range (numberOfSteps):
    x += increasePerStep
    print x


-1.0
-0.857142857143
-0.714285714286
-0.571428571429
-0.428571428571
-0.285714285714
-0.142857142857
-2.22044604925e-16
0.142857142857
0.285714285714
0.428571428571
0.571428571429
0.714285714286
0.857142857143
1.0
```

Comment: Michael, why did you delete this one? I use this one and it seems to work. Is there a potential problem with this one? :O

Comment: @JoanVenge I thought I saw a problem, and then rechecked it a minute ago and found there was no problem, so I undeleted it.

Comment: how is this _more elegant_ than the one proposed by @JoanVenge? both have [magic numbers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber) (`0.01` and `2.0`)

Comment: "both have magic numbers (0.01 and 2.0)"  still more magic is `14`

Comment: Sorry guys I accepted this because I only needed a simple formula to work for this case, not one that would work for others, as I rarely needed this sort of thing, but otherwise I would have accepted Julio's solution (which I upvoted).

Comment: I took the liberty to move the magic numbers to properly named variables, so that the approach is easily understandable. Hope you don't mind, @Michael :)

Answer (score 11):

There is no built-in solution, but probably a good way to solve it is to define your own `range` function:

```
def my_range(start, end, how_many):
    incr = float(end - start)/(how_many - 1)
    return [start + i*incr for i in range(how_many)]
```

And you can use it in a for-loop:

```
>>> for i in my_range(-1, 1, 10):
...   print i
... 
-1.0
-0.777777777778
-0.555555555556
-0.333333333333
-0.111111111111
0.111111111111
0.333333333333
0.555555555556
0.777777777778
1
```

**EDIT:** As @NiklasBaumstark suggested, if your brand new `my_range` function is going to handle a big quantity of numbers it is probably a good idea to use [generators](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator). For that purpose, we'll do just a little modification:

```
def my_xrange(start, end, how_many):
        incr = float(end - start)/(how_many - 1)
        return (start + i*incr for i in xrange(how_many))
```

Comment: You should really use a generator there instead of creating a temporary list.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: you're totally right, I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 11):

If it's OK to use `numpy`, this works fine:

```
import numpy as np
n = 21

for i in np.linspace(-1, 1, n):
    print i
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go with

```
for x in xrange(n):
    print float(2*x)/(n-1) - 1
```

Two things of interest: `xrange` is more efficient than `range`, and there's no need to have two separate iterator variables.

You could wrap this in a function if you find it frequently useful:

```
def linspace1(n):
    for x in xrange(n):
        yield float(2*x)/(n-1) - 1
```

although you'd probably want to make the lower and upper limits parameters as well, as in julio.alegria's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You said you had your answer, but I feel that this is an elegant solution.  It also eliminates the possibility of weird floating-point issues (at least, from the defined range).  It combines the power and flexibility of generators along with string formatting and floating-point values.  Alternatively, you could avoid much of this if you elected to go with the [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module - but that would require a bit more tweaking.

```
def decimal_stepper(start, end, step=0.1):
    while start <= end:
        yield float(start)
        start = float(('%' + str(step) + 'f') % (start+step))
```

An example run:

```
myVals = decimal_stepper(-1, 1)
for x in myVals:
    print x
```

Which outputs:

```
-1.0
-0.9
-0.8
-0.7
-0.6
-0.5
-0.4
-0.3
-0.2
-0.1
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7 
0.8
0.9
1.0
```