# Is there any predefined function that generates a set number of numbers, equally spaced, between two set limits?

Tags: python

I need to generate a list of numbers, equally spaced, between two set limits. As inputs I have the two set limits and the number of numbers that I need and as outputs I have the list.

Is there any predefined Python function that does this, or I have to program it myself?

Comment: you mean a function outside numpy?

Comment: Any predefined function that has what I need

Comment: possibly duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652006/is-there-a-built-in-python-function-to-generate-100-numbers-from-0-to-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the range function.

Syntex:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

Eg:

```py
a = list(range(1,10,2))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Link : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

For getting certain number of points between two limits:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
print(x)
```

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-linspace-python/

Comment: This function tells me the step, but I need to set the list length. Something like: I want 25 numbers, equally spaced, between x and y.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin I have made the changes accordingly.